Are Observables not really asynchronous?
I'm surprised by the order of the output of this Observable example:


<script type="module">


import { of } from 'https://dev.jspm.io/rxjs@6';

console.log("1. before subscribe");
of(["asd"]).subscribe(paramMap => {
    console.log("2. in subscribe");
});
console.log("3. after subscribe");


</script>



This produces this output:
1. before subscribe
2. in subscribe
3. after subscribe

How is this output possible? Shouldn't Observables be asynchronous, and the log in subscribe happen last?

Why do you assume that observables should be asynchronous? Of course they can be asynchronous, if next is called later, but they don't have to be.

This is as documented in the RxJs documentation:

Remember that callbacks provided to subscribe are not guaranteed to be called asynchronously. It is an Observable itself that decides when these functions will be called. For example of by default emits all its values synchronously. Always check documentation for how given Observable will behave when subscribed and if its default behavior can be modified with a scheduler.

And in particular, the documentation for of:

An Observable that synchronously emits the arguments...


"synchronously emits the arguments" means "every time subscribe is being called"?

@Bergi, it means that the callback is called synchronously for every argument given to of. The OP only passed one (array) argument, but if it had been of(1, 2, 3) the output of "2. in subscribe" would have been repeated 3 times before "3. after subscribe" was output. And yes, it is also true that if you would call subscribe again on the same of observable, the callback would be called again for as many times, and synchronously.

thank you for this, i thought by default that Observables are async, but forgot that docs can shed some light.

As mentioned the default for of is sync,
But you can pass an asyncScheduler to make it async
eg.


<script type="module">
import { of,  asyncScheduler } from 'https://dev.jspm.io/rxjs@6';

console.log("1. before subscribe");
of(["asd"],  asyncScheduler)
  .subscribe(paramMap => {
    console.log("2. in subscribe");
  });
console.log("3. after subscribe");
</script>




You should disregard and forget any documentation that clarifies whether observables and promises are async or not.
If you're relying on this knowledge, you're most likely doing something very wrong.
